# Trying to get hellofacebook sample app to run on my acer tablet android v 3.2

Tags: android, facebook

I’m trying to get the sample code to work in the facebook sdk.  When I ru the hellofacebooksample program, it does not do anything.
I clicked on the login button and a doog pop up saying the permissions it would br accessing, “ public profile and friend list)  but no login screen came up.  If I clicked on any of the button like add post, nothing happens.

I tried to unstall the facebook app I had on my device and install the current version.  Strill did not work.  My app is running on a cer tablet android version 3.2